# How to store outcome of switch statement into an object in c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create an object that stores the outcome of the switch statement in c#? Because my end goal is to compare the object in an if statement, and if that's true then it will print a writeline.

```
 switch (results)
 {


 case 1:
    checkingWriter.WriteLine("text");
    break;
 case 0:
    checkingWriter.WriteLine("text");
    error_Found = true;
    break;
 case -1:
    checkingWriter.WriteLine("text");
    error_Found = true;
    break;
 case -2:
    checkingWriter.WriteLine("text");
    error_Found = true;
    break;
 case -3:
    checkingWriter.WriteLine("text");
    error_Found = true;
    break;
 }
```

Comment: We need a bit more detail than this.  Can you provide a sample switch statement for us to look at?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes! i just posted it

Comment: Alright.  So why doesn't the code you posted work as-is?

Comment: I am just tryna store the outcome of the switch into an object, so i can use it to compare to something else in an if statement @RobertHarvey

Comment: Looks like you're doing just fine.  Keep going, and good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing both side effects and the computation of a value; this is a bad code smell and you might consider separating that logic.

To address your specific question: at this time there is no easy way to get a value computed by a particular switch case section out of the switch. However, this feature has been proposed for C# 8.0, so it seems likely that you'll get some version of this. See the link below for the proposal:

https://neelbhatt.com/2018/05/19/c-8-0-expected-features-part-iii-switch-statments/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, something like (but very basic since we do not have any details):

```
var objectToCheck = ...; // Some initialized value or null
switch(...)
{
case ...:
    objectToCheck = ... 
    break;
case ...:
    objectToCheck = ... 
    break;
...
default:
    Error handling
}

if (objectToCheck ==/.Equals(...) ) // Check object
```

Answer (score 0):

create variable before switch statement begins, store the switch case result in variable. After switch ends, use the variable in the `if` condition.

```
var result = null;
switch (caseSwitch)
      {
          case 1:
              result = fn1();
              break;
          case 2:
              result = fn2();
              break;
          default:
              Console.WriteLine("Default case");
              break;
      }

if(result == 'your condition')
    do something
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough details but may this works, or give you a new idea:

```
public class Foo
    {

        public static bool operator !=(Foo foo1, int results){
            return results <= 0;    
        }
        public static bool operator ==(Foo foo1, int results){
            switch(results)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("All gones good");
                    return false;
                case 0:
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing happend");
                    break;
                case -1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Error 183");
                     break;
                case -2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Fatal Error");
                    break;
                 case -3:
                    Console.WriteLine("The user doesn't exists");
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And when you use it:

```
public static void Main()
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            int results = 0;

            // makes some logic that fills results

            if(foo == results){
                Console.WriteLine("Do Something Custom Here");  
            }

            results = -1;

            if(foo == results){
                Console.WriteLine("Do Another Something Custom Here");  
            }
       }
```

It will give you in console something like this:

```
//Nothing happend
//Do Something Custom Here
//Error 183
//Do Another Something Custom Here
```